# Angularjs : how to use key of object to retrieve value of another json object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have an array of json objects

```
$scope.arrary = [{"a":"value"},{"b":"value2"},{"c":"value3"}];

$scope.secondObje = {"a":"this is updated value","b":"this is new value"}
```

i can iterate through 'array' using

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in array">
```

now how can i access value of second object using key

I want something like `{{secondObje.key}}`, how can i do this in angular.

so that i get `"this is updated value"` and `"this is new value"` printed.

Please help me.

Comment: may be : `{{secondObje[key]}}` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code fails because `$scope.arrary` is an array, therefore, `key` in `<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in arrary">` gives you indexes starting from 0 (i.e. 0, 1, 2) instead of alphabets (a, b, c) which you intended.

**Option 1:**
One way to handle this is to change the format of `$scope.arrary` so that you have

```
$scope.arrary = [{"key":"a", "value":"value"},{"key":"b", "value":"value2"},{"key":"c", "value":"value3"}];
```

You can then use the keys on the second object as

```
<div ng-repeat="a in arrary">
    {{ secondObje[a.key] }} <br>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**
However, if you want to keep `$scope.arrary` the way it is, you can use keys on the second object as

```
<div ng-repeat="a in arrary">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in a">
        {{ secondObje[key] }} <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5NzZX/119/)

Here is a working demonstration of these: http://jsfiddle.net/5NzZX/119/

I prefer the first option.